# Interpretation based in the output

Tags: r

I need some help please, i have this file and i'm getting some results i shouldn't but donÄt know where to find for the error, i've been going through every single line of code for the past days and i cannot seem to find it.

So, i have a loop and i should have my results in a txt file.

Now the correct file should be something like:

```
413062.079096717
413062.079096717
413062.079096717
413062.079096717
413062.079096717
```

But i get something like:

```
"x"
"1" 459585.393096583
```

I know this is not much, but based in the output, can you understand anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `write....` command in your code, then make sure you've got the arguments `row.names=FALSE` and `col.names=FALSE`.  You say it's in a loop - if you also don't have `append=TRUE` as an argument, the file will be getting over-written for each loop.  Unfortunately, if the file exists already when you enter the loop, it won't get cleared, so either `unlink` it prior to entering the loop, or have something along the lines of `append=(i!=1)` if i being one identifies the first iteration of the loop

Comment: Great,
Thank you very much!
Please add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is to use the `cat` function:

e.g.

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  X = 413062.079096717
  cat(X, "\n", file='myfile.txt', append=TRUE)
}
```

Notes:

- `"\n"` will print a newline after your variable,
- `file` allows a filename (you can also print to screen at first by omitting this one), and
- `append=TRUE` will make sure you don't keep overwriting the file every time you write